# Fire an event through an element with a partially transparent background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got stuck with solving a seemingly easy issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/HAKvN/3/

By clicking the black box beneath the white bubble you're triggering an event causing an alert to be shown.

The white bubble represents a div with the red border indicating its boundaries. The bubble is a background image saved as a PNG file with an alpha channel.

**I'm trying to fire an event by clicking over a transparent background within a box with the red border (this space is not occupied by the bubble itself) - is it even possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe that can be done easily (maybe if you had all the coordinates in an array) an alternative would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HAKvN/4/ (remove the borders to give a better rendering)

EDIT: a slightly better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HjrCE/2/. The function is `infoBoxSplit` and can be called on any jquery object (eg: `$('.infoCloud').infoBoxSplit(5);​`). It takes one argument that specifies how large each piece should be in height (in this example 5px). The border is just there to demonstrate what is happening.

Comment: That will do. It works the way I expect it to work and therefore I'll stick with that solution.

Comment: Thanks. There is also a check mark under the votes which allows you to select a solution and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not believe what you want to do is possible with javascript.  As far as the script is concerned the PNG is a square block.  It has no awareness of the white speech bubble within the image.

If you want to do something like this, your best bet will probably involve an HTML5 canvas element.

Comment: I agree, JS has no way of accessing the alpha channel of the PNG file unless it's prepared beforehand on the server-side.